# BindableBehavior not updating binding

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin.forms

I have a custom Behavior class inheriting from a bindable behavior class
where I have ItemSource property and the propertyChanged event on the BindableProperty only invokes at creation time not on changed even I call RaisePorpertyChanged

BindableBehaviorClass

```
 public abstract class BindableBehavior<T> : Behavior<T> where T : BindableObject
{
    public T AssociatedObject { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(T visualElement)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(visualElement);

        AssociatedObject = visualElement;

        if (visualElement.BindingContext != null)
            BindingContext = visualElement.BindingContext;

        visualElement.BindingContextChanged += OnBindingContextChanged;
    }

    private void OnBindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnBindingContextChanged();
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(T view)
    {
        view.BindingContextChanged -= OnBindingContextChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        BindingContext = AssociatedObject.BindingContext;
    }
}
```

CustomListBehavior

```
   public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemsSource),
        typeof(IEnumerable<IPerson>),
        typeof(CustomListBehavior), 
        defaultValue: null,
        propertyChanged: ItemsSourceChanged);
    public IEnumerable<IPerson> ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<IPerson>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }
```

ViewModel

```
  private ObservableCollection<IPreson> people = new ObservableCollection<IPerson>();


public ObservableCollection<IPerson>  People
    {
        get => people;
        set => SetProperty(ref people , value, nameof(People));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my view Model I changed instead of instantiating the the local variable like 
this `private ObservableCollection<IPreson> people = new ObservableCollection<IPerson>();`
I do it in before I assign it the new values after creation of the class.